# read local text file content get Nil in swift

Tags: swift, swift5.7

I would like to read the content from one text file in swift the step I did is

1. go to terminal and read/create a file
2. go to Xcode, File -> add file to My Project and select the test_this file into project
3. use the following code to read the content.

```
/// terminal
/// $echo "some content" > /Users/test_this
/// swift
let file = "/Users/test_this"
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
let text = try? String(contentsOf: path)
```

however, after print out file, path and text. text is Nil. file and path looks fine
how do I read the content from a text file in swift?

Comment: You seem to be doing two different things -- 1) Reading a file at `/Users/test_this` (which, by the way, is a very unusual place to put a file 2) Adding a file to your app's bundle and trying to read it. Which do you want to do? Keep in mind that if the answer is #1, if you app is sandboxed, you don't have access to files unless a user selects them first.

Comment: I want to do 2 and I try to add the file into my project directory also. I still get Nil

Comment: You get a file in your bundle by doing something like `Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:)`, not by using an absolute path the file on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this approach, given that you have added the `test.txt` file to your Xcode project.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fileTxt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(fileTxt)
            .onAppear {
                if let theString = readLocalData() {
                    fileTxt = theString
                    print("---> fileTxt: \(fileTxt)")
                }
            }
    }

    func readLocalData() -> String? {
        if let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)
            do {
                return try String(contentsOf: url)
                // alternative
                // let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                // return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            } catch {
                print(error) // <-- here important
            }
        }

        // vadian cleaner alternative
//        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "txt") {
//            do {
//                return try String(contentsOf: url)
//            } catch {
//                print(error) // <-- here important
//            }
//        }
        
        return nil 
    }

}
```

With the `test.txt` file content:

```
Hello World
```

Note: to add the file `test.txt` to your `Xcode` project.

1. open `Xcode` and navigate to your project, ensure the left panel shows the folders/files of your project.
2. open `Finder` and navigate to your `test.txt` file.
3. drag and drop the `test.txt` file from `Finder`  into your Xcode project left panel.

After doing that, `Build` then `run` my code.

Alternatively, you can create a `New File` in Xcode, using: right mouse click on the left panel showing the folders/files,
then select `New File...`, scroll down then select, `Empty` file. Give it a name `test.txt`. And the file will be
created and added to your Xcode project. Open this file in Xcode and type this: `Hello from the test.txt file`.
Build then run my code.

Comment: What is difference?

Comment: don't understand your question here, the difference between what?

Comment: the difference between your code and my code.

Comment: Well the difference is that I'm using the required `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")` 
to read a file that you have added to your xcode project. Is this not clear from my answer? Does my answer not work for you?

Comment: no. it does not work. i think the root cause for me is I do not add the file under my bundle

Comment: As I said in my answer, `...given that you have added the test.txt file to your Xcode project.`. 
To add a file to your project, in Xcode, on the left folder panel, right mouse click, then Add Files to .... 
You can also (recommended) drag and drop the test file from `Finder` 
into your Xcode project left panel (that is, while your Xcode project is open). 
After doing that, my code will work, as it does for me.

Comment: updated my answer with more explanations on how to add the `text.txt` file to your Xcode projcet.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Why not `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "txt")` as you need an URL anyway?

Comment: yes, very good, you can do that, saves one line of code. I'll update my answer with this alternative. Am I missing something obvious that makes all this not work for the OP?